# Delete article is not working when require it

Tags: php, html, pdo

I have problem with article deleting. I have got 2 files(article.php, delete.php). When I require file delete.php in article.php it is not deleting the article, but when i open it itself.. just delete.php, It works. I don't know why its happening. Can someone please help me? thanks. Files below.

This is article.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../connect.php');
include_once('admin.php');
include_once('../includes/article.php');

if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
  $query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 
  ".$_SESSION["user_id"]);
  $query->execute();
  $row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if($row['privileges']==1){
  ?>
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <br/>
    <div class="options">
      <img src="../images/add.png" width="20px" height="20px" style="float:left;"><form method="post"><input class="article" type="submit" name="add" value="Pridať článok">
      </form>
      <img src="../images/delete.png" width="20px" height="20px" style="float:left;"><form method="post"><input class="article" type="submit" name="delete" value="Odstrániť článok"></form>
        <img src="../images/edit.png" width="20px" height="20px" style="float:left;"><form method="post"><input class="article" type="submit" name="edit" value="Upraviť článok"></form>
  </div>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    require_once('add.php');
  }else{
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
      require_once('delete.php');
  }else{
    if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
      require_once('edit.php');
  }}}?>
</body>
</html>

  <?php
  } else{
  header('Location: ../index.php');
  }
 } else{
 header('Location: ../index.php');
 }
 ?>
```

This is delete.php:

```
  <?php

  session_start();

  include_once('../connect.php');
  include_once('../includes/article.php');

  $article= new Article;

  if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){

   if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id=$_POST['id'];

    $query=$pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM articles WHERE article_id=?');
    $query->bindValue(1,$id);
    $query->execute();

    header('Location: ../index.php');
    }

    $articles=$article->fetch_all();

    ?>
    <html>
     <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" />
    </head>
      <body>
       <div class="container">
       <br/>
       <h4>Zvoľte článok, ktorý chcete odstrániť:</h4>
       <form action="" method="post" class="addarticle">
        <select name="id">
         <?php foreach($articles as $article){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>"><?php echo 
         $article['article_title']; ?></option>
         <?php } ?>
        </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Odstrániť článok">
      </form>
      </div>
    </body>
   </html>
  <?php
  } else{
   header('Location: ../index.php');
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: In delete.php, the form you are submitting, can't able to deduct POST of "id" , your form has post of "delete" alone

Comment: @LajosArpad i dont have error, it is just refresh the page. But i dont understand why , when it works if i open just delete.php and when i require it is not...

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are calling `session_start` exactly once:

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

and now to your problem. When you click on the delete button, your `form` is submitted and the only data sent is **delete=Odstrániť článok**, no `id` being sent there. You need to change your form like this:

```
  <img src="../images/delete.png" width="20px" height="20px" style="float:left;"><form method="post"><input class="article" type="submit" name="delete" value="Odstrániť článok"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php /*echo id of the article to be removed*/ ?>"></form>
```

If you do so, upon clicking on the delete button, the `id` will be sent to the server as well. Your delete is executed now without a problem, but the `id` you provide to it is faulty.